# Kotlin script fails to run on Windows - org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.NoDescriptorForDeclarationException

Tags: windows, kotlin, kotlin-native, kotlin-script

when running:

```
 kotlinc -script Day1.kts
```

`Day1.kts`:

```
println("hello")
```

I get:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil (file:/C:/Users/ASUS/kotlin-native-windows-1.4.21/konan/lib/kotlin-native.jar) to method java.util.ResourceBundle
.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
error: compilation failed: Front-end Internal error: Failed to analyze declaration Day1
File being compiled: (1,1) in C:/Users/ASUS/IdeaProjects/adventOfCode2020/Day1.kts
The root cause org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.NoDescriptorForDeclarationException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.BasicAbsentDescriptorHandler.diagnoseDescriptorNot
Found(AbsentDescriptorHandler.kt:18)

 * Source files: Day1.kts
 * Compiler version info: Konan: 1.4.21 / Kotlin: 1.4.21
 * Output kind: PROGRAM

exception: org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.KotlinFrontEndException: Front-end Internal error: Failed to analyze declaration Day1
File being compiled: (1,1) in C:/Users/ASUS/IdeaProjects/adventOfCode2020/Day1.kts
The root cause org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.NoDescriptorForDeclarationException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.BasicAbsentDescriptorHandler.diagnoseDescriptorNot
Found(AbsentDescriptorHandler.kt:18)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.ExceptionWrappingKtVisitorVoid.visitDeclaration(ExceptionWrappingKtVisitorVoid.kt:43)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitDeclaration(KtVisitorVoid.java:453)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitDeclaration(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor.visitScript(KtVisitor.java:78)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitScript(KtVisitorVoid.java:73)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitScript(KtVisitorVoid.java:519)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitScript(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtScript.accept(KtScript.java:69)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImplStub.accept(KtElementImplStub.java:60)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer$analyzeDeclarations$1.registerDeclarations(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:78)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer$analyzeDeclarations$1.visitKtFile(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitKtFile(KtVisitorVoid.java:513)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitKtFile(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile.accept(KtFile.kt:243)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile.accept(KtFile.kt:230)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.ExceptionWrappingKtVisitorVoid.visitElement(ExceptionWrappingKtVisitorVoid.kt:27)
        at com.intellij.psi.PsiElementVisitor.visitFile(PsiElementVisitor.java:35)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor.visitKtFile(KtVisitor.java:73)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitKtFile(KtVisitorVoid.java:69)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitKtFile(KtVisitorVoid.java:513)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitKtFile(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile.accept(KtFile.kt:243)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile.accept(KtFile.kt:230)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:201)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations$default(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:60)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForKonan.analyzeFilesWithGivenTrace(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForKonan.kt:94)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForKonan.analyzeFiles(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForKonan.kt:67)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.ToplevelPhasesKt$frontendPhase$1$1.invoke(ToplevelPhases.kt:86)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.ToplevelPhasesKt$frontendPhase$1$1.invoke(ToplevelPhases.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:115)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.ToplevelPhasesKt$frontendPhase$1.invoke(ToplevelPhases.kt:85)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.ToplevelPhasesKt$frontendPhase$1.invoke(ToplevelPhases.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PhaseBuildersKt$namedOpUnitPhase$1.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:97)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PhaseBuildersKt$namedOpUnitPhase$1.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:95)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:94)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:23)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:94)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:41)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanDriverKt.runTopLevelPhases(KonanDriver.kt:29)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:78)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:35)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:76)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:45)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:227)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit$default(CLITool.kt:225)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(CLITool.kt:214)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$main$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:264)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$main$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:261)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.UtilKt.profileIf(Util.kt:27)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.UtilKt.profile(Util.kt:21)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion.main(K2Native.kt:263)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2NativeKt.main(K2Native.kt:457)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt$main$1.invoke(main.kt:41)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt$main$1.invoke(main.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.mainImpl(main.kt:17)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.main(main.kt:41)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.NoDescriptorForDeclarationException: Descriptor wasn't found for declaration SCRIPT
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.BasicAbsentDescriptorHandler.diagnoseDescriptorNotFound(AbsentDescriptorHandler.kt:18)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.BasicAbsentDescriptorHandler.diagnoseDescriptorNotFound(AbsentDescriptorHandler.kt:17)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.findClassDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:88)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.getScriptDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:65)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer$analyzeDeclarations$1.visitScript(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:89)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitScript(KtVisitorVoid.java:519)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitScript(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtScript.accept(KtScript.java:69)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImplStub.accept(KtElementImplStub.java:60)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.ExceptionWrappingKtVisitorVoid.visitDeclaration(ExceptionWrappingKtVisitorVoid.kt:32)
        ... 58 more
```

I'm using Windows 10, Kotlin Native Windows 1.4.21.
It works fine in Mac.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we figured at the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44049, the problem was in the incorrect archive being downloaded.

> This document mentions downloading kotlin-compiler-1.4.21.zip, while you have probably downloaded kotlin-native-prebuilt-windows-1.4.21.zip